# All the header names in line if condition matched

Tags: awk

In my input file i am having id, batch and 3 condition. The value in condition columns can be 0 or more. I am trying to write the condition column header (which condition 1/ 2 or 3) in the line  after id and batch name column if the condition column value is more than 0. If multiple condition has a value over 0, i am trying to have the conditions separated by coma. Also in the header column I wanted the 3rd column header to be condition name (this case S). I can print the header in the row but not the other stuff. How should I proceed?

**Input**

```
id  Batch S_1   S_2 S_3
E1  A1  0   1   1
E2  A2  0   0   0
E3  A3  6   10  88
```

**Expected Output**

```
id  Batch   S
E1  A1  2, 3
E2  A2
E3  A3  1, 2, 3
```

**What I am trying**

```
NR==1 {    for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
        sub(/S_/,"",$i)}       
for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) h[i]=$i; next}
{
    sep="\t";
    for(j=1;j<=NF;j++) {
        if($j) {
            printf "%s%s", sep, h[j]; 
            sep=", ";
        }
    }
    print ""
}'
```

**What I am getting**

```
    , , 2, 3
    , 
    , , 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: You're populating `h[]` in a loop that starts at 3 (`for(i=3;...`) then printing `h[]` in a loop that starts at `1` (`for(j=1;...`). What values do you expect will be in `h[1]` and `h[2]`? What did you actually want to print instead? Just think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
NR == 1 {
    for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
        h[i] = $i
        sub(/[^_]+_/,"",h[i])
    }
    rest = $3
    sub(/_.*/,"",rest)
}
NR > 1 {
    rest = sep = ""
    for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i != 0) {
            rest = rest sep h[i]
            sep = ", "
        }
    }
}
{ print $1, $2, rest }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
id      Batch   S
E1      A1      2, 3
E2      A2
E3      A3      1, 2, 3
```

I'm setting the OFS to a tab since the 3rd field can contain blanks, if you don't want that then don't do it.

Answer (score 3):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{
   printf "%s%s", $1 OFS, $2
}
NR == 1 { 
   print OFS "S"
}
NR > 1 {
   s = ""
   for (i=3; i<=NF; ++i)
      if ($i > 0)
         s = s (s == "" ? "" : ", ") (i-2)
   print (s==""?"":OFS) s
}' file | column -t -s $'\t'
```

```
id  Batch  S
E1  A1     2, 3
E2  A2
E3  A3     1, 2, 3
```

Comment: this work great with sample ids in single digit. But, if my sample id is S_302 or S_21,  then it fails.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  print $1,$2,"S"
  next
}
{
  val=""
  printf("%s %s ",$1,$2)
  for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){
     if($i>0){  val=(val?val ", ":"")(i-2)  }
  }
  print val
}
'  Input_file
```